# Initializing a hash variable when creating an instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to initialize a class variable as a hash when I create an instance of SomeClass but I keep getting an error. Somewhat new to ruby so any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
class SomeClass < ActiveRecord::Base  
  attr_accessible :some_hash  
  serialize :some_hash,   Hash  

  def initialize(args = {})  
    @some_hash != {}  
  end  
end
```

NoMethodError: undefined method `has_key?' for nil:NilClass
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:52:in`method_missing'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:2827:in `has_attribute?'

from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:2888:in`inspect'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:2887:in `collect'

from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:2887:in`inspect'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:310:in `output_value'

from /opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:159:in`eval_input'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:271:in `signal_status'

from /opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:155:in`eval_input'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:154:in `eval_input'

from /opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:71:in`start'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:70:in `catch'

from /opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:70:in`start'
from /opt/local/bin/irb:13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [article](http://blog.dalethatcher.com/2008/03/rails-dont-override-initialize-on.html) should help you.

In Ruby, you can easily overwrite existing code from gems by simply redefining the method ("monkey patching")

This is the #initialize method you over wrote:

```
# active_record/base.rb
  def initialize(attributes = nil)
    @attributes = attributes_from_column_definition
    @attributes_cache = {}
    @new_record = true
    @readonly = false
    @destroyed = false
    @marked_for_destruction = false
    @previously_changed = {}
    @changed_attributes = {}

    ensure_proper_type

    populate_with_current_scope_attributes
    self.attributes = attributes unless attributes.nil?

    result = yield self if block_given?
    _run_initialize_callbacks
    result
  end
```